# Install Starwind SAN as VM?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, virtual-machines

Is anyone of you using [Starwind 5.x, installed as VM in vSphere v4x.x.? In production environment?

If you do,whats your esperience and how does your configuration looks like?

Thanx for your answer.

Maybe I am asking too much but could you help me out on the following questions.?
Point me to docs?

Two physical servers
Raid 1 > Datastore 1: 2 disks for installing vSphere and VM Starwind
Raid x > 12 disks for use by Starwind VM
- 1.) eagerzeroedthick VMDKs option
- 2.) RDM option
(limit 2Tb > how can I overcome this?)
UserLAN: Gigabit switch or switches for redundancy
StorageLAN: Gigabit switch or switches for redundancy

1. How do I connect these data disks/raid, vmdk or RDM, solely to Starwind?
2. Keep the Starwind VMs tied to one pServer, exclude form HA etc.
3. Starwind in seperate subnet(s) from MS Domain subnet?
4. Seperate subnet for synchronization Starwind, VMware HA

   - 2 pNICs for user LAN each VM, 2 pNICs for VMs to Starwind incl MPIO, 1 pNIC for Starwind sync link, 1 pNIC for VMware HA?
   - 1 vSwitch for user LAN, 1 vSwitch for Starwind, 1vSwitch for VMware HA?
5. Reserve memory for Starwind VMs, equal to best practise for MSSQL?

Thanx Jaap
I 've installed Starwind V5,2 as a VM
10.16.0.8 > Management Network
192.168.2.1 > Storage Network
Starwind is listening to all ports.
Created .img file
Enabled iSCSI initiator, added 10.16.0.8 and-192.168.2.1.
Rescan of the iscsi hba gives zero results. :(

vmkping 10.16.0.8 gives no results
vmkping 10.16.0.250 works ok
vmkping 192.168.2.1 gives no results
vmkping 192.168.2.250 works ok.

Any idea?

Greetz Jaap

I've attached  foto

[here](http://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/1472689-34580/screenshot.1.jpg)

Comment: You are going to run StarWind as a guest on the very same hosts that are going to use it for SAN storage? Seriously?

Comment: You can install StarWind on a VM for test purposes but it's not practical for production purposes.

StarWind needs to reside on a physical server with the disks available locally.

If you do it via a VM you're doubling (or worse) the network overhead needed to deliver any disk data.

Answer (score 1):

I have to ask why are your trying to install Starwind as a VM for anything other than testing???

Generally you want your SAN to operate as quickly and efficiently as possible.  Adding another layer of abstraction (i.e. VMWare) seems like a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: StarWind for testing only? It seems like you didn't even worked with it, or there was another problem. In my case everything worked just fine.

Comment: I wasn't implying that you shouldn't use Starwind for production.  My comment was simply that using Starwind *in a VM* for production seems like a bad idea.